# Discretization of second order ODE, apply Z transform and inverse

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, control-theory, z-transform

I have the following ODE:

$\frac{\mathrm{d^2y(t)} }{\mathrm{d} t} + 2\frac{\mathrm{dy(t)} }{\mathrm{d} t}+4y(t)=e^{-2(t-2)}u(t-2)$

With $u(t)$ being the unit step function. I am than asked to discretize the ODE (with sampling T=1), which gave me:

$y(n+2) + 3y(n) = e^{-2(n-2)}u(n-2)$

Next, I'm told to apply the Z transform to the function and later apply the inverse Z transform to find y(n) (initial values y(0) = y(1) = 0):

$z^2Y(z) + 3Y(z) = \frac{1}{z(z-e^{-2})}$

$Y(z) = \frac{1}{z(z-e^{-2})(z^2+3)}$

The problem is, when I apply the inverse Z transform using Wolfram, I get an enormous y(n) which doesn't seem quite right (that is, I don't think the exercise actually expects this result):

$\frac{(e^{2 - 2 n} (i (-i)^n 3^{n/2 + 1/2} e^{2 n} - i i^n 3^{n/2 + 1/2} e^{2 n} + (-i)^n 3^{n/2 + 1} e^{2 n + 2} + i^n 3^{n/2 + 1} e^{2 n + 2} + 18 e^6) (1 - θ(1 - n)))}{(18 (1 + 3 e^4))}$

I imagine that I can simplify the result using some clever Z transform properties, but I couldn't get very far with that thought. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there, maybe, a nice property of the transform that I could apply here? I've been stuck in this exercise for the last few days now.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform partial fractions and simplify first.
Let,
$${Y(z)} = \frac{1}{z(z-e^{-2})(z+\sqrt3i)(z-\sqrt3i)} =\frac{a}{z}+\frac{b}{z-e^{-2}}+\frac{c}{z+\sqrt3i}+\frac{c^*}{z-\sqrt3i}$$

$z = 0 \Rightarrow a = -\dfrac{e^2}{3}$

$z= e^{-2} \Rightarrow b = \dfrac{e^6}{1+3e^4}$

$z = -\sqrt3i \Rightarrow c =\dfrac{1}{-\sqrt3i(-\sqrt3i-e^{-2})(-2\sqrt3i)}= \dfrac{1}{6(\sqrt3i+e^{-2})} = \dfrac{e^{-2}-\sqrt3i}{6(3+e^{-4})} =\dfrac{e^2(1-e^2\sqrt3i)}{6(1+3e^4)}$

and $c^* = \dfrac{e^2(1+e^2\sqrt3i)}{6(1+3e^4)}$

So,

$\begin{align}\dfrac{c}{z+\sqrt3i}+\dfrac{c^*}{z-\sqrt3i} &= \dfrac{1}{6\sqrt3(1+e^{-4})(z^2+3)}\left[(z-\sqrt3i)(1+e^{-2}i)+(z+\sqrt3i)(1-e^{-2}i)\right]\\&=\dfrac{z+\sqrt3e^{-2}}{3\sqrt3(1+e^{-4})(z^2+3)}=\dfrac{1}{3\sqrt3(1+e^{-4})}\left[\frac{z}{z^2+3}\right]\end{align}$

---

The answer will depend on the Region of Convergence. Let us assume $|z| > \sqrt3 > e^{-2}$

$\begin{align}Y(z) &= \frac{a}{z}+\frac{b}{z-e^{-2}}+\frac{c}{z+\sqrt3i}+\frac{c^*}{z-\sqrt3i} \\&= \frac az + z^{-1}\left[b\frac{z}{z-e^{-2}}+c\frac{z}{z+\sqrt3i}+c^*\frac{z}{z-\sqrt3i}\right] \\
y(n) &= a\delta(n) +(be^{-2(n-1)}+c(-\sqrt3i)^{n-1}+c^*(\sqrt3i)^{n-1})u(n-1) \\
y(n)&=-\frac{e^2}{3}\delta(n)+\left[\frac{e^{8-2n}}{1+3e^4} + c(-\sqrt 3 i)^{n-1} + c^*(\sqrt 3 i)^{n-1}\right]u(n-1)\end{align} $

---

> $$c(-\sqrt 3 i)^{n-1} + c^*(\sqrt 3 i)^{n-1} = \dfrac{e^23^{\frac n2-\frac12}\left[e^23^\frac 12 \left(i^{n} + (-i)^{n}\right) + i^{n-1}+(-i)^{n-1}\right]}{6(1+3e^4)}$$

So,

$$y(n) = -\frac{e^2}{3}\delta(n)+\dfrac{6e^{8-2n}+e^23^{\frac n2-\frac12}\left[e^23^\frac 12 \left(i^{n} + (-i)^{n}\right) + i^{n-1}+(-i)^{n-1}\right]}{6(1+3e^4)}u(n-1)$$

This can be further simplified using $\frac{i^n+(-i)^n}{2} = \frac{e^{i n \frac\pi2} + e^{-i n \frac\pi2}}{2} = \cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$

Finally (**for the assumed ROC**),

> $$y(n) = -\frac{e^2}{3}\delta(n)+\dfrac{3e^{8-2n}+e^23^{\frac n2-\frac12}\left[e^23^\frac 12 \cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}{2}\right)\right]}{3(1+3e^4)}u(n-1)$$

Similarly you can find for different ROC's

Comment: I think you forgot the 'e' on the denominator towards the end, but this seems right. However, it still doesn't look like the answer the exercise asks for (not that there's anything wrong, it's just that past problems never had such extensive results). Anyways, there might be something wrong in the problem's description, so I'll look into that

Comment: One other thing: when you compute the inverse Z of the fractions being multiplied by z^-1, shouldn't the resulting functions of n also be time shifted? Having something like be^(-2(n-1)) . . . ?

Comment: @JoaoLima Yeah I missed those parts. Thank you for letting me know. I'll again look into it if it can be solved in a simpler way